# WebExecute timeout

Tags: web-access, version-12

There isn't much tuning freedom available in the [WebExecute](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WebExecute.html) method. If a page takes too long to load you only see a spinner or a blank for `CapturePage`. Does someone see how to let the method wait a bit?

Comment: Adding a manual `Pause[]` in between `WebExecute["OpenPage"]` and `WebExecute["CapturePage"]` could be a possible solution, but I'm not sure if you're looking for something more elegant than that.  For websites I've looked at the `WebExecute["OpenPage"]` command only returns once the page is loaded.  Can you give an example of a website that returns but then takes addition time to load other elements of the page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an unavoidable problem due to the nature of the modern web. You never know when a page has finished loading, because modern websites have Javascripts that just continuously refresh the page, so some websites will not have loaded completely after `WebExecute` returns from `"OpenPage"`. When `WebExecute` returns, there's still a possibility that scripts change the page. The only thing you can really do, is use

```
WebExecute[session, "OpenPage" -> url];
Pause[n]
WebExecute[session, "CapturePage"]
```

to wait for a while and give the scripts on the page time to stabilize.

Answer (score 3):

At a slight tweak on Sjoerd's solution, you can execute any JavaScript on the page to see if a particular document state has been reached (modern web pages are almost never 'static' so you have to do something more specific to ascertain you are in the state you want to capture an image of):

```
result = WebExecute[session, "JavaScriptExecute" -> "... javascript code..."]
```

And then make a decision based on what `result` is.

Comment: Will consider Sjoerd's proposal as the solution, since it does `CapturePage` without extra JavaScript. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @Arnoud Buzing, in my experiments with `WebExecute` with `JavascripExecute` parameter, it doesn't typically return a value. Is that different for you?

Comment: @VictorK. Even when you use the `return` statement?

Comment: @ArnoudBuzing ah, you are right, of course - I'm not sure why I didn't think about using return, but it works pretty well: e.g., `WebExecute["JavascriptExecute" -> "return([1,2,'this'])"]` return a list as you would expect, and `WebExecute["JavascriptExecute" -> "return(document.body)"]` returns a rule `{"ELEMENT" -> "0.5427856833586193-1"}` where the element can be feed to e.g. `WebExecute("ElementText"->id)`.

Comment: @ArnoudBuzing thanks for writing WebUnit, btw - very useful package, I'm using it extensively to extract information from a bunch of dynamic web pages that has no other recourse. I'm sure you have a ton of other more important tasks, but it would be cool if WebExecute would support `FindElementsFromElement` (https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#dfn-find-elements-from-element) eventually - it's one of the few commands defined by WebDriver that's not currently supported. Here is a use case: you want to extract a bunch of information fields (phone, email, name, etc.) from a bunch of contacts.

Comment: In some cases, each contact can be accessed as a parent element, with all the details underneath - it's much easier to express relative XPaths to access the children, esp. when some contacts have some of the information missing.